# What's the intention of \e

Tags: php, regex, ansi-escape

I was wondering about this escape sequence.
The [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) says that `\e` represents "escape"
Well, i've googled it and found about **ANSI Escape Sequences**,
i dont know if this `\e` refers them.

From Wikipedia:

> ANSI escape sequences are characters embedded in the text used to control formatting, color, and other output options on video text terminals.

But i cant see how this escape sequences and PHP can interact.
I don't know if all the things that post are correct.

Can someone talk about this topic and show examples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP cannot only be used with a web server; PHP scripts can run from the command line, like this:

```
$ php foo.php
```

If one makes a PHP script which is meant to run from the command line (e.g. the `cake` command which ships with CakePHP), `\e` can come in handy when you want to do colors and formatting in terminal emulators.

You can find more about these escape sequences on [this page](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php).

Answer (score 3):

The sequence of characters `\e` is used by PHP to represent the [`ESC` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character), `0x1B` in ASCII (and UTF-8 and other ASCII-compatible encodings). It's helpful to have a way to represent [non-printing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) with printable characters (namely `\` and `e`, in this case) because it's not easy to write such characters with a standard keyboard  (let alone read them on the screen). These sequences are generally called "escape sequences".

The manual page you are linking to is simply saying "if you're writing a regular expression and want to match on the `ESC` character, you can use `\e` to do so. The other `\...` sequences similarly represent characters and sets of characters that are hard to directly input.

As you discovered, `ESC` has many uses, among them ANSI escape sequences, which are used to modify the output of a command-line program, commonly to add colors, such as `\e[...m` where `...` is one or more [Select Graphic Rendition codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (search for "SRG" on that page). This isn't specific to PHP; it is the terminal, not the executing program, that understands these escape sequences. Any program (written in any language) that outputs the appropriate sequences of bytes in a compatible terminal will trigger this behavior.

You can see this behavior easily in Bash, try running the following commands in your terminal:

```
$ echo -e '\e[31mRED TEXT\e[m'
$ echo -e '\e[42mGREEN BACKGROUND\e[m'
$ echo -e '\e[5mBLINKING?\e[m'
```

Most terminals will style the output of the first command in red, and the second in a green background. However many terminals intentionally do *not* support blinking text, for the same reason the HTML `<blink>` tag is generally unsupported - it's annoying :)

Needless to say, the term "escape sequence" is used in a number of different contexts to mean slightly different things. But in general an escape sequence is some special sequence of characters that has a specific meaning beyond just the characters themselves.

Answer (score -1):

There are many escapes.

`\b`: backspace
`\n`: new line
`\r`: hard return
`\e`: escape
etcetera...

They all  do different things when they are output.